# Search and Filter wordpress plugin search results show page title as BLOG

Tags: php, wordpress, search, filter

How do I remove the page title "BLOG" from the search and filter plugin search results. This page is autogenerated. Here is the link

[Search results page](http://www.binsidragas.com/euromatechnew/?sfid=37038)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p id="demo"></p> <!-- title tag that needs replaced -->

<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function urlCheck() {
if(
window.location.href=="YOUR URL LOCATION HERE "
)
{
document.getElementsById('demo').innerHTML = "This is what I wanted !!"
}else{
document.write('<div>testing my super loaded div code sample</div>')
}
}
urlCheck() /* autoLoadFunction */
//-->
</script>
```